# Assign to a whole column of a Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, multi-index

I have a DataFrame(called `midx_df`) with a MultiIndex, I want to assign values from a whole column of another DataFrame(called `sour_df`) with single level index to `midx_df`.

All of index values of `sour_df` exist in the top level index of `midx_df`, I need to specify the level-1 index to add/modify all values of rows with same level-1 index.

For example:

```
beg_min = pd.to_datetime('2023/03/18 18:50', yearfirst=True)
end_min = pd.to_datetime('2023/03/18 18:53', yearfirst=True)
minutes = pd.date_range(start=beg_min, end=end_min, freq='1min')
actions = ['Buy', 'Sell']
m_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([minutes, actions], names=['time', 'action'])
sour_df = pd.DataFrame(index=minutes, columns=['price'])
sour_df.index.rename('time', inplace=True)
sour_df.loc[minutes[0], 'price'] = 'b0'
sour_df.loc[minutes[1], 'price'] = 'b1'
sour_df.loc[minutes[3], 'price'] = 'b2'

midx_df = pd.DataFrame(index=m_index, columns=['price'])
print(midx_df)

midx_df.loc[(beg_min, 'Buy'), 'price'] = 123    # works but only for one row!
midx_df.loc[(end_min, 'Buy')]['price'] = 124    # doesn't work!
print(midx_df)

midx_df.loc[(slice(None), 'Buy'), 'price'] = sour_df    # doesn't work!
print(midx_df)

midx_df.loc[(slice(None), 'Buy'), 'price'] = sour_df['price']    # doesn't work!
print(midx_df)

#midx_df.loc[(slice(None), 'Buy')]['price'] = sour_df['price']    # doesn't work!
#print(midx_df)

midx_df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Buy'], :] = sour_df    # doesn't work!
print(midx_df)
```

What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question. The problem here is your indexes are not aligned: `('time', 'action')` vs `'time'` only so pandas can't set correct values.

You have to reuse the index of `midx_df` to reindex `sour_df`. `pd.concat` can bu used to accomplish this task:

```
midx_df.loc[(slice(None), 'Buy'), 'price'] = \
    pd.concat([sour_df], keys=['Buy'], names=['action']).swaplevel()
print(midx_df)

# Output
                           price
time                action      
2023-03-18 18:50:00 Buy       b0
                    Sell     NaN
2023-03-18 18:51:00 Buy       b1
                    Sell     NaN
2023-03-18 18:52:00 Buy      NaN
                    Sell     NaN
2023-03-18 18:53:00 Buy       b2
                    Sell     NaN
```

Or use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`:

```
midx_df.loc[(slice(None), 'Buy'), 'price'] = \
    sour_df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([sour_df.index, ['Buy']]))
```

Details:

```
>>> midx_df.loc[(slice(None), 'Buy'), 'price']
time                 action
2023-03-18 18:50:00  Buy       NaN
2023-03-18 18:51:00  Buy       NaN
2023-03-18 18:52:00  Buy       NaN
2023-03-18 18:53:00  Buy       NaN
Name: price, dtype: object

>>> pd.concat([sour_df], keys=['Buy'], names=['action']).swaplevel()
                           price
time                action      
2023-03-18 18:50:00 Buy       b0
2023-03-18 18:51:00 Buy       b1
2023-03-18 18:52:00 Buy      NaN
2023-03-18 18:53:00 Buy       b2

>>> sour_df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([sour_df.index, ['Buy']]))
                        price
time                         
2023-03-18 18:50:00 Buy    b0
2023-03-18 18:51:00 Buy    b1
2023-03-18 18:52:00 Buy   NaN
2023-03-18 18:53:00 Buy    b2
```

Now the indexes are well aligned to set values.