# Pandas: raise an error if indexes don't match when concat'ing or merging?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concatenate (index-wise) or merge two pandas DataFrames. However, I want this to fail if the two DataFrames don't share the same index (potentially MultiIndex).

Does pandas offer a way to assert this when combining such datasets?

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': rng.integers(0, 10, size=3)}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': rng.integers(0, 10, size=3)}, index=['a', 'b', 'd'])
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

```
     A    B
a  0.0  0.0
b  7.0  6.0
c  6.0  NaN
d  NaN  2.0
```

I'd like this to raise an error, since the indexes don't match.

Do any of pandas's merge functions (merge, concat, join, etc) offer any sort of index checking?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your datasets? Can you check this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/75775941/15239951

Comment: yes will add an example!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no function like this but you can add `assert (df1.index == df2.index).all()`

Comment: well `(df1.index == df2.index).all()` might not work as expected due to ordering. Maybe `set(df1.index) == set(df2.index)`?

Comment: Your question is really interesting and I don't have any robust code to offer you. Thanks @QuangHoang for the `set` idea.

Comment: Would it make sense to try to use the `df2` index to assign into `df1`? Something like `df1.loc[df2.index, "B"] = df2["B"]`? This fails when `df2` contains an index that `df1` does not have (but not vice versa). I think the easiest would really be to check if the indices match between the two dataframes.

Comment: @KenHBS that's a good idea. I just wish there was a way to concat two dataframes index-wise and make sure it was all one-to-one. Relatedly to your solution, I was trying to think if using `DataFrame.assign` would be useful here but i don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook the method (or function):

```
real_merge = pd.DataFrame.merge
def fake_merge(left, right, *args, **kwargs):
    assert set(left.index) == set(right.index), 'Indexes are different'
    return real_merge(left, right, *args, **kwargs)
pd.DataFrame.merge = fake_merge
pd.merge = fake_merge
```

**Disclaimer: it's just for demonstration purpose, I think you should not use this code in production. You can keep the `assert` idea before merge, concat, join, ...**

Try it:

```
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
...
AssertionError: Indexes are different


>>> df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
...
AssertionError: Indexes are different
```